# CORS error appears when using a fetch request, But not when clicking a link in the browser

Tags: node.js, typescript, cors, fetch

Im using Node.js and TypeScript to try and use an api that returns a JSON.

When i click on the link in my browser it works perfectly fine, i can see the JSON file.

However, when i make a simple fetch request i get a CORS ERROR in my browser console.
I tried to use { mode: 'no-cors' }, but then i dont have access to the body.

I checked my url and its fine.

can anyone tell me why is that?

my function:

```
async function fetchFeed() {
try {
    const response = await fetch(`${BASIC_URL}`, {
    })
    console.log(response);
    const posts = await response.json()
    console.log(posts);
    
} catch (err) {
    console.log('could note get posts' + err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: it answers why but still no solution. is there a solution other than contacting the server side ?

Comment: No, there is not.